# Uploading images to azure blob storage with windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-mobile-services

I have been trying for the longest while to find a way to upload images using windows azure blob storage with windows phone. I tried using windows azure storage client for windows phone but that does not seem to be working any more. I also tried about 2 other nuget packages and I also tried a web service that will handle the upload for but that didn't work out well as I wasn't completely how I should connect the web service to my phone app. I tried also uploading it using windows azure mobile service. Could anyone give me some pointers on how I should go about getting this to work?

Problem with windows azure storage client for windows phone

Install-Package Phone.Storage -Version 1.0.1
Attempting to resolve dependency 'SilverlightActivator (≥ 1.0.3)'.
'Phone.Storage 1.0.1' already installed.
ProjectName already has a reference to 'Phone.Storage 1.0.1'.

But no reference added to visible in reference folder

Problem with mobile services 
Tried this: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/upload-images-to-storage-dotnet/

but could not find a Storage client library for Windows phone 7

Comment: Mind posting some of the code that you're using to make it easier to pinpoint your problem?

Comment: Well I removed most of it form my project but I will do it again in a while and repost here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain a shared access signature (SAS) from your blob storage to be able to upload.

You can do so using your own web service that uses the storage client SDK to get the SAS and send it back to the phone, or you can use the Mobile Service for the same purpose.

http://www.nickharris.net/index.php/2012/11/12/how-to-upload-an-image-to-windows-azure-storage-using-mobile-services/

Comment: This is for windows 8, what am I suppose to do when I reach here Download the Storage Client libraries for Windows 8 click here.

Comment: You don't need. Use Mobile Services to generate the SAS URL and then use a WebClient on Windows Phone to POST your photo to that URL.

Comment: @sabbour I have sas url with me and Account name. I want to upload file using that. How i can do that. I have seen the documentation given by Azure but I am not getting where i have to set the url and how to use it for android platform. Please check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847102/upload-file-with-azure-mobile-storage-using-sas-shared-access-signature

Comment: @sabbour the link reference you have given is not working. Can you please update it. Please also check my question i have put in comment. I need some solution to it if you can help in that.